# Code organization in mvc

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

In our web application we have repositories with CRUD operations and a generic finder function, for instance `userRepository.Get(u => u.Username == someString)`.
And `UserRepository` will return only `User` objects.

But what if I have a complex query which do the join between `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3` and returns `CustomObject` which contains some properties from these 3 tables.

Should I put those queries in a Service layer?
Should repositories only contain basic CRUD and finder function and return basic entity object and nothing else? I ask because some people told me that no queries should be in Service layer...

Comment: this is where you need to look at Domain driven design, you can do it using repository but its not that generic when your application is complex

Comment: You can also have a look at this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-accurate-is-business-logic-should-be-in-a-service-not-in-a-model

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a type `CustomObjectRepository` which encapsulates the joining of tables and returns only `CustomObject`s. Exactly how to implement the generic finder function depends on what type of ORM you use (it will be trivial with EF, complicated but not at all impossible if you do manual mapping).

Answer (score 1):

You can either have a Business logic View oriented Repository which stands one level on top of your current repository and name in according to that business logic.

Or you might apply hierarchical logic assigning this query to one of your existing repositories.

For example.
If you have 3 tables (Driver - Car-  DriveSessions) and you need to display the User's First-Last Name, The car make,license plate and all the info of the last Drive session .

Using the 1st approach you would create a "Summaries" Repository. 
Or you would add this in the "Driver" repository since all of these entities are oriented around a "Driver".

My opinion is adding a Repository in top of EF is an overkill . Some business models are so complex that it's kinda impossible to abstract everything on single repositories. That's why EF was designed for, with IQueryables. Encapsulating all your entities behind concrete repositories you lose most of the candy EF has to offer.

[Opinions about using Repository pattern on top of EF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework)

In my application i think **not a single**  entity is non complex.  Using a concrete per table repository would decrease performance and increase development time **A LOT**

Comment: There are other ways to write repositories on top of EF, that make use of IQueryables but still provide a wrapping layer around the ORM-specific code - see for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrtechnocal/archive/2014/03/16/asynchronous-repositories.aspx (of course, there is still a coupling between the client code and EF here, because operations on IQueryables which are not supported by EF will throw exceptions, but separation is much better than just using EF directly).

Comment: Yes I use a  somewhat similar approach , but i think i wouldn't call that a classic "Repository Pattern"  .  It is mostly a Wrapper around entity framework i think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Query Object pattern. It's a much more SOLID approach. Furthermore, separating querying and CRUD, creates opportunities to use different, more appropriate infrastructure that might be better suited to custom querying. Also see: [this](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

If you can, investigate what Vaughan Vernon calls a 'use cas optimal query' and beware of the smell that he calls 'repository masks aggregate mis-design'.